# Referring to a struct type inside a namespace

Tags: c++, linux, struct, g++

Is it possible to refer to a struct type (e.g. epoll_event declared in sys/epoll.h) inside a namespace?

I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/epoll>

namespace N1 {
namespace N2 {
class C {
    public:
    void print() const {
        std::cout << sizeof(struct epoll_event) << std::endl;
     }
};
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    N1::N2::C c;
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

And g++ gave me this error:

```
nested.cpp:3:21: error: sys/epoll: No such file or directory
nested.cpp: In member function ‘void N1::N2::C::print() const’:
nested.cpp:23: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘N1::N2::epoll_event’
```

And for some reasons, those "global" struct belongs to std won't have the issue above (I tried to replace "struct epoll_event" with "struct tm", and it works fine).

So 2 questions:
1. What's the correct way to refer to those "global" non-std struct?
2. Why referring to those "global" std struct is treated differently by the compiler (at least g++ 4.4.x)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **always deal with the first error message first. Subsequent errors may simply be consequences.** Here, the first error reported was `error: sys/epoll: No such file or directory`. You ignored that and wanted to fix the second error, which was caused by what is reported in the first.

Comment: Right, my bad. I completely missed the first error but jumped to the last one. sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include correct header file, otherwise your code is correct. There is `epoll.h` in `sys` but no `epoll` header

update

```
#include <sys/epoll>
```

to

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
```